# ‘ion-toast’ is not a known element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I know this is a common issue, but,
all the fixes i've seen so far don't work, im 99% sure im importing the correct modules. Here's my issue.

using the [ion-toast docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast) i am trying to implement a simple toast in the app component, but i can’t compile the app because of the error

`'ion-toast' is not a known element`

app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.comp…html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu contentId="menuContent">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title> Money </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-list>
               ...
        </ion-list>
      </ion-menu-toggle>

      <ion-toast [isOpen]="isToastOpen" message="No Internet Connection" [duration]="5000"
        (didDismiss)="setOpen(false)"></ion-toast>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

  <ion-router-outlet id="menuContent"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 7.1.1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.2.18
   @angular/cli                  : 12.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 5.2.1
   @capacitor/android : 5.2.1
   @capacitor/core    : 5.2.1
   @capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : 1.7.2

System:

   NodeJS : v16.20.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 8.19.4
   OS     : Linux 5.15
```

Any idea what’s wrong here? i don’t want to use CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA.
Everything else is working btw, the error only happens when i add ion-toast which is weird.

Thanks in advance guys

Edit 1: i have created a new ionic app with the same imports in the app.routing, app.component and app.module (only difference was the new app threw an error on the empty entryComponents: [] which i deleted) and has only the toast and it's working correctly, so most probably the problem is not with the imports.

Edit 2:
package.json file

```
{
  "name": "expenses-calculations",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^5.0.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@capacitor/network": "^5.0.6",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: Can you rebuild your app again and check?

Comment: @Chellappanவ using the command `npm run build` it throws the same error `Error: src/app/app.component.html:34:7 - error NG8001: 'ion-toast' is not a known element`

Comment: Is it possible to create stackblitz?

Comment: @Chellappanவ i couldn't duplicate the error on a new app unfortunately

Comment: can you share your pacakge.json configurations?

Comment: it looks like https://ionicframework.com/docs/updating/6-0#angular ionic-6 only angular 12+ supports please check the link

Comment: @Chellappanவ i don't quite understand your point, i am using ionic 7 not 6

Comment: According to your package json ionic/angular version is 5.5.2

Comment: @Chellappanவ oh, so in ionic 5 ion-toast is not available?

Comment: I am not sure please update the package and see whether works or not

Comment: I have same problem with Angular 15, Ionic 6.5.2

Comment: @Boat i've wasted too many hours on this issue to no vail, a workaround to generate the toast from your .ts file, async presentToast() {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: 'No Internet Connection',
      duration: 3000,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Dismiss',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            if (navigator["app"]) {
              navigator['app'].exitApp()
            }
          },
        },
      ],
    });
and then call it this.presentToast() when you need it